# what does "outright" mean in rates world?

Tags: swaps, terminology

For example, what does "outright" mean in outright OIS swap? Another similar question, what does "USD fedfund is marked as outright" mean? Thank you

Comment: You can think of "outright" as meaning "simple", "straightforward" (in the sense of no complications or qualifications needed). An outright OIS swap would be based on a single interest rate, such as SOFR. A spread or basis swap would be based on the difference between 2 rates (for ex SOFR vs Fed Funds) and could be implemented by having two outright swaps in opposite directions one for each rate , or could be a customized contract. See also this post https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25320/what-does-it-mean-to-receive-outright

Comment: @nbbo2 why not just say vanilla or plain vanilla which essentially means the same? The abundance of jargon really do puzzles me sometimes.

Comment: @Hasek I think outright is narrower than vanilla i.e. outright $\subset$ vanilla. I have only seen it used to designate vanilla, spot-starting swaps (I think the origin is that outright means "immediately" in standard English). So for example options are excluded when somebody says "_I hedged the trade using outright purchases_".

Comment: @hasek: I think Vanilla : US English, Outright: British English but I am not sure of this

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Comment: if I understand correctly, outright curves are related to basis curves, for instance, OIS-Libor3m basis can be calculated using "outright" OIS curve and "outright" Libor3m curve

Comment: 'outright' means sensitivity to level of rates. 'outright' in fedfunds means an exposure if the fedfunds rate moves up or down. The alternative would be 'basis' where the exposure of fedfunds would be relative to the movement of another curve, say the sofr curve. In that instance, one may make money if the fedfunds curves moves up **or** down, so long as it is positively compared to the movement of the sofr curve.

Answer (score 2):

When trading derivatives via "voice" sometimes you got asked if the position is outright. The intention behind this is to understand if your trade idea and your request is part of a larger construction.

Simply speaking: If you ask me for a bid/ask for X I'll might ask you if this trade is "outright".
Your reaction could be "no i'd like to trade X vs. Y as a pair trade"
Then I would price you both instruments at the same time.

A different case could be if you had a fixed income portfolio (consisting from swaps and bonds) and the risk manager asks you "why do you have swap X open?". Your answer could be "This is an outright trade". Therefore the RM knows that this position is not for hedging purposes.